# JPA Criteria: CriteriaBuilder over NestedObject field

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

Here my entity:

```java
public class QdCF implements Diffable<QdCF> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "QDCF_ID")
    private Integer id;

    // @Column(name = "QDCF_AMBIT")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "QDCF_AMBIT")
    private String ambit;
}
```

Now, I've changed `ambit` field to `ManyToOne`:

```java
public class QdCF implements Diffable<QdCF> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "QDCF_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "QDCF_AMBIT")
    private Ambit ambit;
}
```

Above code works fine.

However, I've a custom JPA criteria like this:

```java
public static Specification<QdCF> likeCodi(String codi) {
    return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        return criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(QdCF_.ambit).as(String.class), "%" + codi + "%");
    };
}
```

Above code doesn't works now since:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Expression to CAST cannot be an entity : qdcf0_.QDCF_AMBIT

Any ideas about how to troubleshot it?

Comment: Hey! I'm trying to do the exact same thing and getting the same error.
Did you have any luck? Did you manage to do it somehow?